# Should the FAQ focus a bit less exclusively on engines?

Tags: discussion, scope

When asking my question [Sound system volume fades in/out erratically](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/3520/sound-system-volume-fades-in-out-erratically) I was a bit unsure if this site was suitable due to a missmatch between the FAQ (emphasis mine)

> Questions related to the maintenance and repair of motor vehicles and their accessories, internal combustion engines, even in applications other than automotive **so long as the question is related to engine or engine accessories**.

The run-on sentance makes it unclear whether the "engine only" aspect relates to all questions on the site or only "applications other than automotive". From a glance at the front page and [Nick C's comment here](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/3520/sound-system-volume-fades-in-out-erratically#comment3360_3520) it sounds like the "engine only" bit either doesn't apply to all questions. Could the copy be improved a bit?

I'm thinking something more like:

> Questions related to the maintenance and repair of motor vehicles and their accessories. Questions related to internal combustion engines in applications other than automotive are also allowed so long as the question is related to the engine or engine accessories.

Or something else to clarify non-engine, but mechanic related car issues are on topic (electical, breaks). It sounds like *requiring a mechanic* is the main qualifier, not the engine.

Answer (score 4):

If it came from the factory and it's broke, I think it should be on-topic.

Comment: Heh. A bit blunt but I'm not entirely opposed to this view...